# Write to Keychain/SharedPreferences with GoMobile

Tags: go, gomobile

I am looking to write to keychain(iOS)/sharedprefs(Android) from GoMobile. Does anyone have any experience or packages to support this?

My preference is to avoid writing the custom integration as I assume it would be fairly common functionality.

Thanks,

Comment: I am writing this integration myself, will update ticket answer when it is in any reasonable shape.

Comment: did you end up writing something for this?

Comment: Apologies. Yes I did start to

Comment: Any update on this?